# How do I upload a file to s3 using boto3 in python on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, amazon-s3, boto3

All of the examples online seem to use boto.  What code can I use to upload a file to s3 using boto3?

I'm trying to use the code from the official documentation, but I'm getting an error that version 4 authentication failed.

Comment: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ please try to search the web.

Comment: For posterity, the official docs leave out a very crucial point, as docs often do.  That's the purpose of this post.

Comment: Which crucial point? [Quickstart](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html) seems to provide exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: , region_name='REGION_NAME') is required if you are unlucky enough to pick a region, like us-east-2 where default values don't work.

Comment: `region` can be set in the config file (as described in the quickstart) and `region_name` is explained clearly in the documentation for `session` and  `resource`. BTW you may want to explore profiles in your `.aws/config` and use a `session` object.

Comment: In my case it can't. I've updated the question to refer to my specific situation and why it's necessary to include it in the resource call.

Comment: @AChampion No I can't.  There are no config files on heroku.  No permanent file system.

Answer (score 7):

Put your keys in the keyfile according to the [quickstart guide](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#using-boto-3) and then use the following code:

```
       import boto3
       s3 = boto3.resource(service_name='s3', region_name='REGION_NAME')
       data = open('PATH_TO_FILE_ON_DISK', 'rb')
       s3.Bucket('BUCKET_NAME').put_object(Key='FILENAME_ON_S3', Body=data)
```

The official documentation does not make it clear that the region name is required or else you may get an error, and it's not possible to store the configuration file for the region on heroku. It must be included in the resource call.

Comment: This does not answer the question "What is the new syntax?".

Comment: In what way does it not?  If you copy and paste that code it works perfectly.  Anyway, it doesn't matter. I just needed to fill some space because I've been searching for this snippet of code for almost 4 days. The documentation is not clear.

Comment: Okay I am not going to argue on this and I will just remove my downvote.

Comment: My vote is locked and I cannot remove it so please do some editing on your answer.

Comment: `Body` needs to either be the data (e.g. `'this is my data'`) or a file type object e.g. `open('PATH_TO_FILE_ON_DISK')`. Your example would just be an object with the string `PATH_TO_FILE_ON_DISK` in it not the file contents.

Comment: @AChampion I'm afraid you're just incorrect. I copied the code directly from my project which is currently working in production. The PATH_TO_FILE_ON_DISK is indeed exactly as I described it. It's possible that my answer is incomplete, and if it is I'm happy to accept an edit, but it's not incorrect..

Comment: @JeremyT You may want to check your code, `upload_file()` takes a filename but `put_object()` doesn't - from the docs `Body (bytes or seekable file-like object) -- Object data.`. And your linked quickstart also shows an `open()`.

Comment: @AChampion  I literally copied and pasted the code from production and replaced the arugments with placeholders.  I checked it again. Either you are incorrect, or the documentation is incorrect and what I've done above works perfectly fine.  In production, PATH_TO_FILE_ON_DISK points to a file sitting in /tmp

Comment: @JeremyT I'm not saying your code doesn't work, I'm just telling you the contents of your object in S3 is not the file contents but just the filename, try `s3.Object('BUCKET_NAME', 'FILENAME_ON_S3').get()['Body'].read()` and check the contents.

Comment: @JeremyT Aren't you troubled this code made it into 'production', and you are welcome.

Comment: @AChampion Considering my app has one developer and 5 non paying users in alpha, no not really.

Answer (score 1):

Since heroku doesn't have access to your [AWS config file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html#cli-configure-files-where), you'll have to use [environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). You can then use any of the various [s3 file upload methods](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html).

```
from os import getenv

import boto3

boto_kwargs = {
    "aws_access_key_id": getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
    "aws_secret_access_key": getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
    "region_name": getenv("AWS_REGION"),
}

s3_client = boto3.Session(**boto_kwargs).client("s3")

s3_client.upload_fileobj(<f>, <bucket_name>, <object_name>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference here's how you can fix the issue of v4 authentication being used for all new regions - set `signature_version` in the config file:

```
--- .aws/config ---
[default]
output = json

[profile myprofile]
region = REGION_NAME
s3=
  signature_version = s3
#  addressing_style = path

--- .aws/credentials ---
[myprofile]
aws_access_key_id = <access-key>
aws_secret_access_key = <secret-key>

--- python ---
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='myprofile')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
with open('PATH_TO_FILE_ON_DISK', 'rb') as data:
    s3.Object('BUCKET_NAME', 'FILENAME_ON_S3').put(Body=data)
```

Alternatively:

```
s3.Object('BUCKET_NAME', 'FILENAME_ON_S3').upload_file('PATH_TO_FILE_ON_DISK')
```

Comment: Unless you are aware of a hidden feature, config files don't work on heroku

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Heroku released a good article on uploading files to S3 in Heroku. [Direct to S3 File Uploads in Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python).

According to instructions, you need to specify AWS Credentials and Bucket name in your Heroku App config vars.

> In order for your application to access the AWS credentials for signing upload requests, they will need to be added as configuration variables in Heroku:

```
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID =xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY =yyy
Adding config vars and restarting app... done, v21
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     => xxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY => yyy
```

> In addition to the AWS access credentials, set your target S3 bucket’s name:

```
heroku config:set S3_BUCKET = zzz
Adding config vars and restarting app... done, v21
S3_BUCKET     => zzz
```

*Note:* if you are testing locally before deployment, remember to add the credentials to your local machine’s environment, too. It was described above how to make it with a config file.