# How do I replace or get a file in Heroku

Tags: python, json, heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-api

I am creating a discord bot and I use a JSON file to store everyone's data , the problem is that when I have to update my game and if I upload the code to Heroku it will rewrite everyone's data there is two ways I can fix this,

Get the JSON file from Heroku
or Rewrite the code in Heroku with the new code (best option)

If you know how to do either of these commands please let me know down below! :)

Answer (score 1):

File storage on Heroku is emphemeral. You'll need to store the JSON somewhere else.

The Heroku [documentation](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) explains how to deal with this.

*Storing the data in a persistent storage option is the way to go.*

Comment: do you have a suggestion of a youtube video that will follow me thorugh the steps of the answer you commented?

Comment: Personally I'm not that big of a fan of YT videos when talking about dev, so I won't be able to help you here...

Comment: could you please reply with steps on how to do the method u just suggesteed

Comment: the more I think about that part of my answer, the worse I think it is. I've removed it because of this. You really need to use a proper persistent storage option. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201156/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-s3-using-boto3-in-python-on-heroku) for uploading files to Heroku S3 in python

Comment: Here is a blog post presenting some options on how to store files on an external storage https://medium.com/geekculture/files-on-heroku-cd09509ed285

Answer (score 0):

Either way is to use heroku postgres database which will help you to store data...

Answer (score 0):

I am using repl.it to host my bot now and it works so far, freecodecamp made a great video explaining how to host a discord bot on youtube